# How do I get the currently used code page in UWP?

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

I want to know which character set is currently used. I'm using c++/winrt to build an UWP app.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps generally use Unicode. A few "A" versions of functions (like `CreateEventA`, `CreateMutexA`, `OutputDebugStringA`, etc.) are available because those strings are purely internal and not localized.

The recommendation is to build with `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` enabled, use the `W` versions of Win32 APIs, and void using `TCHAR` and all multibyte C/C++ Runtime functions.

**That said, recent versions of the Windows 10 SDK have added more of the ASCII functions back to the UWP API partition in order to support more 3rd party libraries. `GetACP` is supported.**

> This was not supported in the Windows 10 Anniversary Update SDK (14393) which was the last Windows 10 SDK to officially support VS 2015, but if you are using VS 2017 or later with a newer Windows 10 SDK you should have it defined for the `WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION` for `WINAPI_FAMILY_APP` in `winnls.h`.